# UIWebView give different result in iphone 5s and 6 how can we solve it

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I have used this code but it appears different when it appears in iphone 5s and 6. I want to make it present same as in iphone 6 in all iphone version

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    HTMLContent= @"myUrl";
    webView.delegate = self;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:HTMLContent];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];


}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    [SVProgressHUD show];
 }

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webViews {

    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

}
```

Image is below first is of **iphone 5s** and **second 6**

[image]

Comment: The added text in your edit adds some clarity, the screen shots alone don't; I've retracted the close vote.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and help

Answer (score 0):

Try using webkit,

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var webView: WKWebView = WKWebView()  // creating a reference to to the WKWebView

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero)
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(webView)

    webView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false) // disable auto-generated constraints

    let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraints([height, width])


    let url = NSURL(string:"your url")


    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10.0)

    webView.loadRequest(request)

}
```

dont forget to **import WebKit**

Hope this solves your problem...

Comment: Basically, he's suggesting to use WKWebView instead of UIWebView. But, the question was how to fix this in UIWebView. Isn't there any way to solve this in UIWebView?

Comment: Simply create a new swift project,copy paste this code and find whether this solves your problem...

Comment: @Rashmi....after ios8 ,  WKWebView is a replacement to UIWebview....then why to use the old one .. :)